# how to store Settings per customer (not per application and not per user) in ClickOnce-Excel-Addin

Tags: vb.net, vsto, clickonce, app-config

I am working on a VSTO-Excel-Addin (VB.NET) that we are about to sell to different companies.

The addin will (hopefully) be used by a couple of users of each customer. We are using ClickOnce for a web-based deployment.

The addin provides some default-settings - that is no problem with the app.config. User-specific Settings are also working fine with ClickOnce.

However what makes quite some headache is how to store settings per customer. Database-connectionstrings for example cannot be stored on the application-level but it would also be painfull for all users to change the Connection-string manually. What I would imagine is another layer (per Company) where this sort of Setting can be stored.

One alternative would be to create one VSTO-Project per customer but this would bring a lot of disadvantages since we are updating the addin quite regularly.

I would be happy about any ideas!

Regards,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

I would show Excel's built in connection properties dialog and let each client configure this themselves.

You really shouldn't be distributing connection strings for all your clients as part of a shared package. It'll be a maintenance nightmare.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/connection-properties-HA010175443.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, Connection strings are just an example. We have additional settings such as treshhold for ABC-Clusters (the addin is by the way some sort of BI-solution based on Excel and Powerpivot) where we provide default values, companies however may have their Company-specific default.

Answer (score 0):

What about storing the settings as custom properties in Book.xltx and copy it to 
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

This is how you can programatically [read and create Custom Properties in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dhxe2d75.aspx).

When a new workbook is created then all the properties from Book.xltx will be available for New Workbook as well. But this solution may not work if the existing workbooks are opened so yo might have to explicitly add these properties when any existing workbooks are opened using the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand the problem. :)

How about storing all the settings in an offsite database that you maintain and using a webservice to allow the settings to be read and set and giving each client a unique license number that would allow them to access this webservice.

That way the individual users would only need a license number to set it up.